# Google oAuth login - How to allow only whitelisted emails to log into my app

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm creating a web app and decided to use google authentication for its ease of use.
Thing is, I want to only let certain emails login. All other emails should not be able to login!

How do I do that?

I'm aware that I can send the auth token to the backend, verify it with google's library, and then filter the emails but... there should be an easier way, I hope?

Comment: Add a check in your code after the login if the email is not approved log them out and refuse them access.

Comment: I'm aware I can do that but isn't there some sort of a more elegant way to do it via Google. Just like there is allowing -only-  specific domains to be able to use your login. It seems natural to expected a similar solution for specific mail instead of doing it manually.

Comment: there isnt.   There is no way for you to know who they are logging in as until they have logged in and the request has been returned to you.  Nor is there a way for you to limit the login within your project on google developer console.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider how Open id and oauth work.    You are technically forwarding a user over to googles login page.   They login and approve any apis on Googles site you have no way of knowing who they are until they are redirected back to you.

Nor is there any way to limit the users who can login to your client directly in Googles Developer console for your project.  TBH i think that would be really hard for them to administrate.

Your best bet is going to be checking the users email when they return and decide that that time if they may login or not.   It would be also be a good idea to do a [revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) on any credentials google returns to you if you dont want them to have access.